# Detecting Gaps in data from combination of 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, grouping

Given the following table setup:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `errors`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `errors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=190441 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `stored_pictures`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stored_pictures` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_url` (`url`),
  KEY `idx_picture_id` (`picture_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2145543 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to be able to process the missing pid values that do not exist in `stored_pictures` or `errors`

For example given:

```
stored_pictures pids:
1
5
6
7
8
9
15
19
20
21
22
23
24
25

errors pids:
2
4
14
17
```

I need to get a list of:

```
3
10
11
12
13
16
18
```

and then work them into a php array for processing. I am also thinking I need to setup an index on pid for both tables to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd thing to want to do. Why not forget about the missing pids and move on? Anyway...

```
    CREATE TABLE ints(i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

    INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

    CREATE TABLE stored_pictures (pid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

    INSERT INTO stored_pictures VALUES (1),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(15),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25);

    CREATE TABLE errors (pid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

    INSERT INTO errors VALUES(2),(4),(14),(17);

    SELECT i3.i*100 + i2.i*10 + i1.i + 1 missing_pid
      FROM ints i1
      JOIN ints i2
      JOIN ints i3
      LEFT
      JOIN 
         ( SELECT pid FROM stored_pictures
            UNION
           SELECT pid FROM errors
         ) a 
        ON a.pid = i3.i*100 + i2.i*10 + i1.i + 1
      JOIN
         ( SELECT MAX(pid) max_pid 
             FROM 
                ( SELECT pid FROM stored_pictures
                   UNION
                  SELECT pid FROM errors
                ) x
         ) b
        ON b.max_pid >= i3.i*100 + i2.i*10 + i1.i + 1
     WHERE a.pid IS NULL;
```